# How is "OXEN" the answer to "They're neat!"?

Tags: word, cryptic-clues

I had a crossword clue:

> They're neat!

The answer was "Oxen"

I cannot see the link.

---

<sub>Source: The Scotsman Newspaper Cryptic Crossword 02/07/22</sub>

Comment: The Chambers Dictionary is quite helpful. Traditionally any word used in a cryptic crossword should be listed in Chambers and, indeed, “neat” has a relevant definition there (archaic or dialect -- seems to be of Scots origin so makes sense to see this clue in The Scotsman).

Answer (score 12):

This is a [cryptic definition clue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword#Cryptic_definition):

> [Neat](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/neat) as a noun is another word for Oxen (see definition 2).
>
> So the answer is Oxen as, they are literally neat!

Comment: At least in American English, I think this would be a quite difficult clue. OED describes the definition as "archaic and regional", but doesn't mention which region(s). Would this be considered equally tricky/obscure/difficult in Scotland?

Comment: @chepner would agree, but would need a Scottish linguist to confirm! It is definitely an archaic British word, wiktionary has listed Shakespeare using it for example - but as a Brit can’t say I’ve ever heard it used before

Comment: @chepner agreed regarding AmEn, I've also been doing WSJ/NYT crosswords for years and years and not once recall coming across this term. (Just meaning, it's certainly a very hard clue)...Though I did also just learn that cows are neat too!

Answer (score -1):

It is similar as a the term for a group of crows being a 'murder'.
[But then for Oxen](https://www.etymonline.com/word/neat).

Comment: It's not a term of venery like "murder". The term of venery would be "drove", as in "a drove of neat" ([ref 1883](https://www.proquest.com/openview/5838fe93ea9e6b0b/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=3029)).

Comment: I think "collectively" in that etymology just refers to the term not being restricted to any particular species.

Answer (score -2):

I would guess this is one of the word with a nordic background. "Naut" (pronounced more like "nout") is a slightly arcaic word for cows and/or oxen in Norwegian.

Comment: This might be related to the etymology of the word, but probably not what the crossword author intended. (I didn't downvote; I think your answer is reasonable, but probably incorrect.)